# Kotlin: Massive amounts of ConsPStack, how can I avoid?

Tags: performance, reflection, collections, kotlin, garbage

How can I avoid the massive amount of `ConsPStack` that are created by my application? When are these created? My application: https://github.com/Jire/Abendigo

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE (2016-09-05): the issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/f4a1aa640eed4b00bbc25f63edffc4acbf956638) and is going to be available in Kotlin 1.0.5.

Kotlin reflection implementation is using [pcollections](https://github.com/pcollections/pcollections) to cache `KClass` instances for different classes. Large amount of `ConsPStack` instances probably means you're using reflection on a lot of *different* classes. As I mentioned in another answer, reflection implementation is not optimized at all, so issues like this are somewhat expected at the moment.

If this issue is really critical for you, I would recommend to cut down `KClass` creation by using Java reflection where possible. Also, as an extreme solution, you can try clearing the contents of the described cache at a particular moment. Here's the [corresponding code in Kotlin project](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/reflection.jvm/src/kotlin/reflect/jvm/internal/kClassCache.kt). Since the cache (`var K_CLASS_CACHE`) is private, you'd need to use Java reflection to get access to it.

Comment: I am only using reflection to retrieve the `KClass` on a handful of classes (`Byte`, `Short`, `Int`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `Boolean`, and `ByteBuffer`). I do refer to these through a reified generic type of a function which is also only passed these types.

Comment: As you suggested I was able to remove all of them by replacing all `KClass` with `Class` and using reflection to get the Java class via `Example::class.java` :-)